# Binary operations 1011 & (~0 << 2)

Tags: algorithms, binary, binary-operations

My thought process to solving this is that `1011 & (~0 << 2) = 1011 & (1 << 2) = 1011 & 0100 = 0000.` But my book says the answer is 1000, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure what this means

Comment: Same thing as before

Comment: Can you explain with more words?

Comment: So your saying ~0 << 2 = 111?

Comment: Shift left operator has precedence over negation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really a mathematics question...

If we assume for example a 16 bit word size, then $\sim\!0=1111\,1111\,1111\,1111$ and $(\sim\!0 <\!< 2) = 1111\,1111\,1111\,1100$. The rest should be clear.